# Django NoReverseMatch- cannot figure out why it is raising this

Tags: django

Why is Django returning a NoReverseMatch? I am trying to have my app redirect the user when it detects that the user trying to edit a post is not the post's author. However, Django returns a NoReverseMatch when i try to do this.

URLs:

```
path('new/', views.NewPost, name='NewPost'),
path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.editPost, name='editPost'),
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', views.deletePost, name='deletePost'),
path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.commentPost, name='commentPost'),
path('post/<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', views.viewPost, name='viewPost'),
```

View:

```
def editPost(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = pk)
        if post.author == request.user:
            form = PostForm(instance = post)
            return render(request, 'editPost.html',  {'form': form, 'post': post})
        else:
            return redirect('viewPost',pk = pk, postURL : post.postURL)
```

Comment: Please always show the full traceback and the actual code - `return redirect('viewPost',pk = pk, postURL : post.postURL)` is not valid Python and would give a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `url.py` inside of your app? Then you would need to prepend the name of the app with the view name. So for example your app is called `blog` then your view name would be `blog:viewPost`